# Revision history lists a different user as the question author

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, revision-history

[A question's main page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23999456/4356188) says that user3586720 asked it, and user duskwuff edited it. [The revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23999456/revisions) says that user duskwuff asked it, and there's no mention of user user3586720.

Whas goin' on here?

Comment: If you think that looks funny, you missed the oddest part... the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23999456/timeline) says it was *answered* the day before it was asked.

Comment: @Catija [Another question's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26716255/timeline) says that it was answered **4 years** before it was asked!

Comment: Moderator redact revision history?

Comment: Remove the support tag and add the **bug** tag.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Don't know fo sho if it's a bug. Maybe it's [status-bydesign], like a moderator changed the revision history.

Comment: @sag It is a bug as it seems. If it's a _status-by-design_ a moderator will add that tag. But not adding the bug tag will leave this post out if their attention if they filter questions with the tag bug.

Comment: @sag maybe 2 questions were merged, and only the newest "asked" one was kept in the timeline.

Comment: @sag About the other question, it's because [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7091918/4284627) was merged with it and those answers were originally answers to the older question.

Comment: The revision history says duskwuff "deleted 38 characters in body", which is simply an edit, not a post (which should make one assume something is missing there). Although the timeline indeed incorrectly says they asked it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The original revision of the question (i.e. the state the question was first posted in) was redacted by a Stack Exchange employee after it was found to contain sensitive information, leaving just duskwuff's edit as the only remaining revision. I don't remember if this usually leaves an empty stub in the revision history if it's a later edit that gets redacted, but I wouldn't rule out an edge case or a bug causing the appearance of just one "original" revision by a different author here.

Comment: Can moderators search for mod-redactions/see a list of them or can you only see them when you have the link to a question where one was made?

Comment: @TylerH: We can see a list of recent redactions, but this one is too far in the past that we kinda need a link to the question.

Comment: @TylerH: In fact, this one is from 2014 - which far pre-dates the system that we use now that tracks redactions. Before this was introduced, redactions involved a CM deleting revisions outright (*which* might explain the wonky revision history...), and I mostly determined this specific instance from the fact that someone had flagged asking for a redaction.

Comment: Yeah... That old system was kinda horrible, *especially* if you had to touch the first revision (which... was often the case). The other side-effect of this is that there's literally no record of the title in the post's revision history - and so if you go to edit it, the title starts off blank!